# Parse Query - Combining OR statements with AND

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Is anyone aware of how to combine OR statements with AND in Parse for iOS?  So I essentially want to do something like this SQL statement:

```
select * from hotels where (city = 'New York' OR city = 'Chicago') AND (price < 1000 OR price > 2500)
```

There's a lot of documentation for combining a series of OR clauses in Parse using the `orQueryWithSubqueries` method, but I've been unable to find anything solid for combining OR statements with the AND operator like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can make it easier using `NSPredicate`:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"city = 'New York' OR city = 'Chicago' AND price < @1000 OR price > @2500"];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Hotel" predicate:predicate];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Comment: I like this answer, and for most cases it would probably work.  Unfortunately, the predicate I would like to apply to my query is significantly more complex than what I had in my question (that was just an example), so Parse fails to run the query because the predicate `had an OR with >4 subpredicates after normalization`

Comment: @benjammin I did read in the docs that parse cannot handle those complicated predicates. It's a shame, really, because it should be able to accommodate requests like yours. Maybe try posting on the parse google group for a solution from parse directly..

Answer (score 2):

I believe this sort of query is a bit of a pain with Parse, as you'll need to expand out the OR queries due to each of the OR queries needing to be complete. I think the below will probably do what you're after. (I'm guessing at your classname here too).

```
PFQuery *cheapNYQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Hotels"];
[cheapNYQuery whereKey:@"city" equalTo:"New York"];
[cheapNYQuery whereKey:@"price" lessThan:@1000];
PFQuery *expensiveNYQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Hotels"];
[expensiveNYQuery whereKey:@"city" equalTo:"New York"];
[expensiveNYQuery whereKey:@"price" greaterThan:@2500];
PFQuery *cheapCHQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Hotels"];
[cheapCHQuery whereKey:@"city" equalTo:"Chicago"];
[cheapCHQuery whereKey:@"price" lessThan:@1000];
PFQuery *expensiveCHQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Hotels"];
[expensiveCHQuery whereKey:@"city" equalTo:"Chicago"];
[expensiveCHQuery whereKey:@"price" greaterThan:@2500];
PFQuery *hotelQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[cheapNYQuery, expensiveNYQuery, cheapCHQuery, expensiveCHQuery]];
// Run hotelQuery.
```

You could make the above more generic/reusable by using arrays of inputs for hotels and prices, and loop through them generating the queries for the OR, and adding them to a mutable array.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately my actual query is significantly more complex than what I had in my question (that was just an example), so if I go down this road, I eventually get a runtime error saying `Error: too many $or clauses` for my query.  The code would also be really complex I think.